# Parsing text translations

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, parsing

Hi I'd like to get this into Excel Columns of

> Phrase, Translation, %YES

```
<tr>
            <td>Phrase in a language</td>
            <td>Translation</td>
            <td>

                <span id="Accuracy">

                        <a href="javascript:YES(#####);"><img src="/images/YES.gif" border="0"></a>(70%)      
                        <a href="javascript:NOT(#####)"><img src="/images/NOPE.gif" border="0"></a>(30%)

                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I'm using Notepad++ to get it into .csv and remove text between < >

```
<.*?>
```

And in the end this is what I get

```
            Phrase in a language
            Translation




                        (##%)      
                        (##%)
```

After I tried to remove line breaks and replace them with commas

```
[\r\n]+
```

There is of course a lot of phrases and translations, this is just one of many, so...

Any ideas how to easily make it into the three columns, please?

No need for the second %, but it's easy to just delete a whole column in excel I guess if it can't be parsed out.

Thanks

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239). HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. since you are using notepad++.. I suppose, just continue to do :

1. Trim leading and trailing space
2. Remove Emtpy lines

we should get :

```
Phrase in a language
Translation
(##%)
(##%)
```

Assuming these are in cell A1:A4, in sheet1. (And I also assume the next 4 line is the same as these..) Then just put this formula in A1 of Sheet2. Then drag to C10.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN(),TRUE)
```

You should get..

```
Phrase in a language    Translation (##%)
```

Hope it solves. ( :